# How to display friendly error message on page and cancel controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

From a view 'x', when the user clicks on 'Edit Item', the Controller action that renders the 'Edit' page is also checking for the user's permissions to that page.

What I'm trying to do is to check for those permissions and if the user does not have them, I would like to display an error message on that 'X' view and cancel the controller action.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult EditPage(int? itemId)
    {
        var model = new EditPageModel();
        if (itemId.HasValue)
        {
            var obj = new Item(itemId.Value);

   // Check for user's edit permission before we do anything else.

     var request = SecurityRequest.Create(obj, Item_Edit);
     Request.Execute(() => SecurityManager.ValidatePermissions(request));
            if (!request.IsValid(Item_Edit))
            {
                //skip the rest and return error
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                // Need Help Here!!!
            }

      // Mode code executes      
      return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: For the error message, don't forget the large, friendly letters:http://mantia.me/images/dontpanic_large.jpg

Comment: Could you not check the permissions before and just not show the edit link?  Why let them see it if they can't edit?

Comment: Not showing the edit link at all would not be possible. In the view where the Edit button has been placed, there is a list of different items that the user can/can't edit. Upon selection of each item, we need to determine whether he can edit or not. Ideally we would disable/enable the Edit button based on this but since that would require a call back to the controller, we're just saving it for when the user actually clicks on the 'edit' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this (and this is an example of what I use in a current project) is to create your own [`ActionFilter`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs). Here's my example:

```
public class UserAuthenticatedAction : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (IsContextFromLoginController(filterContext))
        {
            return;
        }

        //...Do whatever you need to check.

        if (userNotAllowed){
            SetRedirectToLoginErrorPageForContext(filterContext);
        }

        return;
    }

    private static void SetRedirectToLoginErrorPageForContext(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "controller", "Login" },
                    { "action", "LoginError" },
                    { "targeturl" , filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString()} }
                });
    }

    private static bool IsContextFromLoginController(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = GetCurrentControllerName(filterContext);

        return controllerName.Equals("Login");
    }

    private static string GetCurrentControllerName(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
    }
}
```

To use this filter, in the global.asax.cs file, I have this line in `Application_Start()`:

`GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new UserAuthenticatedAction(excludeActions, allowedRoles));`

That means the attribute is executed whenever an ActionMethod is called. Basically it checks if the user is allowed to access a specific url and if that user is not allowed, then the `filterContext` is set to redirect them back to the login page.

I also check whether the current url is already the login page; if that's the case then don't bother doing the security check.

I guess there are more fancy ways of doing this, depending on your requirement, but the above method works fine for our needs.

Comment: this is a nice answer. I havent used ActionFilters, so this reply will spur me to have a goosey later. THanks.

Comment: agree. This is the best way but it is not what I ended up using. Regardless, I think it is 'the answer'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX request to call the `EditPage` action. If permissions are granted, it could return a callback to redirect to a full edit page (to an action like `EditPageView`). Otherwise, a callback to an error message could be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can always redirect to the error page and display an appropriate  message.

```
if (!request.IsValid(Item_Edit))
{
     //skip the rest and return error
     Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
     ViewBag.errorMessage = "Sorry you do not have access to this page";
     return View("Error")
     // Need Help Here!!!
}
```

And the in your error page (should have one in the shared view folder) you can add the following line

```
@ViewBag.errorMessage
```

**EDIT**

If you dont want to redirect to error page and stay on page x you can do the following

```
if (!request.IsValid(Item_Edit))
{
     //skip the rest and return error
     Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry you do not have access to this page");
     ModelForPageX modelX = new ModelForPageX();
     // do any other setup you need to in order to render page X
     return View("X",modelX)

}
```

This assumes you have a `@Html.ValidationSummary` on the view for page X
if not add the following line

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Unable to process the requested action:")
```

Comment: Ideally, I would like to avoid redirecting the user to an error page.

Comment: sorry misunderstood the original question.